# Проблема обработки слота при нажатии кнопки в классе формы Dialog with Buttons Bottom (Qt)

Tags: qt, dialog, сигналы-слоты

Приветстсвую! Столкнулся с непониманием работы слота в Qt. У меня есть класс формы Qt `Designer Dialog with Buttons Bottom`. Я хочу обрабатывать нажатие кнопки OK по разному, в зависимости от того, что выбрал пользователь. Если он выбрал изображение в диалоговом окне, то следует создать графическое представление и графическую сцену. Если же он не выбрал изображение `(QPixmap(file_name).isNull())`, то я отображаю `QMessageBox::warning` и заново открываю окно с выбором изображения. Я ожидаю, что если пользователь после первого неудачного выбора выберет изображение корректно, то с графической сценой проблем не будет. Однако тут я ошибся, т.к. в этом случае открывается диалог выбора, а затем просто программа завершается.
Я связываю это с тем, что почему-то `ConfigurationDialog` уже закрылся и `view->show();` не отобразилось. Но мне не совсем понятно, как тогда обработать эту ситуацию и почему она вообще возникает?

Проблемный кусок:

```
void ConfigurationDialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()

{
    if (QPixmap(file_name).isNull()){
        QMessageBox::warning(0, QString("Предупреждение!"), QString("Вы не выбрали изображение!"));
        QString selectedFilter("Images ");
        QList<QByteArray> format_list = QImageReader::supportedImageFormats();
        selectedFilter += "(*." + format_list.join(" *.") + ")";
        file_name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Открыть"), QDir::currentPath(), selectedFilter);
    }
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView;
    GameLogic *g = new GameLogic;
    g->setup(ui->frame->value(), QPixmap(file_name));
    view->setScene(g);
    view->show();
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался быстрее чем думал. Оказывается, `QDialog` (от которого я наследую свой класс `ConfigurationDialog`) вызывает `on_buttonBox_accepted()` уже после закрытия формы диалога. Для того, чтобы избежать это, я переопределил метод void `QDialog::accept();`
Теперь обработка сигнала accept() (при нажатии кнопки OК) выглядит следующим образом:

```
void ConfigurationDialog::accept(){
    if (QPixmap(file_name).isNull()){
        QMessageBox::warning(0, QString("Предупреждение!"), QString("Вы не выбрали изображение!"));
        emit ui->browse_button->clicked();
    }
    if (!QPixmap(file_name).isNull()){
        QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView;
        GameLogic *g = new GameLogic;
        g->setup(ui->frame->value(), QPixmap(file_name));
        view->setScene(g);
        view->show();
    }
    QDialog::accept();
}
```